# useSelector not updating when store has changed in Reducer. ReactJS Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-hooks

I am changing the state in reducer. On debug I checked that the state was really changed. But the component is not updating.

**Component:**

```
function Cliente(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const cliente = useSelector(({ erpCliente }) => erpCliente.cliente)
    const { form, handleChange, setForm } = useForm(null)

...

function searchCepChangeFields() {
    //This call the action and change the store on reducer
    dispatch(Actions.searchCep(form.Cep))  
        .then(() => {   
            // This function is only taking values ​​from the old state. 
            // The useSelector hook is not updating with store
            setForm(form => _.setIn({...form}, 'Endereco', cliente.data.Endereco))
            setForm(form => _.setIn({...form}, 'Uf', cliente.data.Uf))
            setForm(form => _.setIn({...form}, 'Cidade', cliente.data.Cidade))
            setForm(form => _.setIn({...form}, 'Bairro', cliente.data.Bairro))                  
        })
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
 case Actions.SEARCH_CEP:
        {
            return {
                ...state,
                data: { 
                    ...state.data,
                    Endereco: action.payload.logradouro,
                    Bairro: action.payload.bairro,
                    UF: action.payload.uf,
                    Cidade: action.payload.cidade                    
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: In my case, I was using useSelector instead of useAppSelector with Typescript.  It silently fails just like this.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> NOTE: you better start using [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started) to prevent references
> in you code its a better and almost a must way for using redux

the problem your facing is very common when handling with objects,
the props do not change because you're changing an object property but the object itself does not change from the react side.

even when you're giving it a whole new object
react doesn't see the property object change because the reference stays the same.

you need to create a new reference like this:

```
Object.assign(state.data,data);

return {
  ...state,
  data: { 
    ...state.data,
    Endereco: action.payload.logradouro,
    Bairro: action.payload.bairro,
    UF: action.payload.uf,
    Cidade: action.payload.cidade                    
  }
}
```

> to add more you can learn about the Immer library that solves this
> problem.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! I`m trying to solve this for more than 3 hours and I don`t see anything about this. You just save me a lot! Thank you

Comment: `initialState = {
  result: [],
  isLoading: true,
  isOrderCreated: false,
  error: undefined
};
`
My reducer not updating this 
 `
 case PLACEORDERFAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true
      }
`
can someone help please

Comment: Is it me or there is not a single difference with the OPs code and this answer?

Comment: @oyalhi  your right I edited this answer and made a mistake I canceled my last change now there is a diff

Comment: In Object.assign(), where did the second argument "data" come from?

Comment: @Adebayo its the new object to assign to the old data obj

Comment: where does the data object come from?

Comment: @eladBA the `data` object is not an incoming argument so you are pulling it from an unknown location. From normal redux the only way to get to that data is from state.data. if you are putting a `new object` there then it would need to be {} there

Comment: @eladBA many thx man.  Changing to ```const nextDevs = [...devs]``` solved the problem.

Comment: does redux toolkit include immer?

Comment: @AliBinNaseer yes

Answer (score 23):

It's not necessary to

```
Object.assign(state.data, data);
```

always when changing data of arrays or objects

```
return(
  object: {...state.object, a: 1, b: 2},
  array: [...state.array, 1, 2, 3]
)
```

this 3 dots (`...`) ensure that you create a new object. On redux you have to always create a new object, not just update the state. This way redux won't verify that your data has changed.

When having nesting objects or arrays, is the same thing

Just have attention to:

```
initialState = {
 object: {
     ...object,
     anotherObject:{
        ...anotherObject,
        a: 1,
        b: 2
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Doing it this way did not provide the expected results I had to go with elab AB's answer. I tried all kinds of spread operations.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, the Object.assgin is not recognize
Update with ES6 syntax.

```
updatedConnectors = state.connectors
```

This will create a reference to the current state. In ES6, that introduce the ... to make new reference.

```
updatedConnectors = { ...state.connectors }
.....
return  {
    ...state,
    connectors: updatedConnectors
};
```

use this to extract and copy new reference. That will trigger state change too

Update Sep/27/20
I've wrote some utils function to handle this, Let try this

```
//Utils
export const getStateSection = ({ state, sectionName }) => {

  const updatedState = { ...state }
  const updatedSection = updatedState[sectionName]
  return updatedSection
}

export const mergeUpdatedSection = ({ state, sectionName, updatedValue }) => {
  const updatedState = { ...state }
  updatedState[sectionName] = updatedValue
  return updatedState
}
```

Then In any reducer, It should use like this:

```
//reducer
const initState = {
  scheduleDetail: null,
  timeSlots: null,
  planDetail: {
    timeSlots: [],
    modifedTimeSlots: [],
    id: 0
  }

}
.....  
const handlePickTimeSlot = (state, action) => {
  let planDetail = getStateSection({ state, sectionName: 'planDetail' })
  // do stuff update section
  return mergeUpdatedSection({ state, sectionName: 'planDetail', updatedValue: planDetail })
}
```

Comment: what is your code? did you add ... at return state?

Comment: yea, i had to create a new object first, then update it. ... wasn't enough to trigger an update.

Comment: @JasonG This is call spread out object of ES6. you can search for this key work and get the idea. This regard to memory handling of JS. This way always work for me. Which version of React are you using

Comment: This also did not provide the needed results. No matter how many different ways spread was implemented I had to go with elab AB's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the edit queue for elab BA is full.

The accepted answer here is what he meant by data being there

```
case MYCASE:
  let newDataObject = Object.assign(state.data, {...action.payload});
  // or 
  // let newDataObject = Object.assign(state.data, {key: 'value', 'key2': 'value2' ...otherPropertiesObject);
  return {
    ...state,
    ...newDataObject
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem, you should understand how the React is working. It is expected behavior

In your case you are invoking

> dispatch(Actions.searchCep(form.Cep))
> .then(() => {...some logic...}

But all of this work in ONE render, and changed store you will get only in the NEXT render. And in `then` you are getting props from the first render, not from the next with updated values. Look for example below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { selectCount, incrementAsync } from "./redux";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const value = useSelector(selectCount);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const incrementThen = () => {
    console.log("value before dispatch", value);
    dispatch(incrementAsync(1)).then(() =>
      console.log("value inside then", value)
    );
  };

  console.log("render: value", value);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{value}</p>
      <button onClick={incrementThen}>incrementThen</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And output

```
value before dispatch 9
render: value 10
value inside then 9
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting edge case that can happen when modifying the file where you create your Store.

If the file where you have your redux store `Provider` component (usually App.tsx) does not get reloaded by React's hot module reloader (HMR) but the redux store file gets modified and therefore reloaded by HMR, a new store is created and the store `Provider` in your App.tsx can actually end up passing an *old instance of your redux store to `useSelector`*.

I have left the following comment in my `setup-store.ts` file:

```
/**
 * Note! When making changes to this file in development, perform a hard refresh. This is because
 * when changes to this file are made, the react hot module reloading will re-run this file, as
 * expected. But, this causes the store object to be re-initialized. HMR only reloads files that
 * have changed, so the Store Provider in App.tsx *will not* be reloaded. That means useSelector
 * values will be querying THE WRONG STORE.
 */
```