# useSelector not updating value after dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I can't find a solution online, I've been following tutorials online and this seems to be the correct way to update my store and then retreive the updated value but it does not work.

Here is my code:

my action

```
dispatch({type: 'RESPONSE_TIME'})
```

my reducer

```
  case "RESPONSE_TIME":

      const newState = {
        ...state,
        filters: {
          ...state.filters,
          response_time: '12',
        }
      }
      return newState;
```

my view

```
const filters = useSelector(state => state.ad.filters);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('look', filters.response_time)
  }, [filters.response_time])
```

My issue is the filters value is not updated in my view, even tho when I check the state inside my reducer, it is updated.

Comment: It makes sense since your state looks like so: state.filters.response_time so probably its should be state.filters.ads

Comment: Yes but if with dispatch you set every time `response_time` to `12` redux state is not updating and `useEffect` will be never triggered....

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito it's initial value is 'all', so it should it least rerender when i first set it to '12'.

Comment: I agree with you. Of course this first time setting should come from a component that already read `all` value in `useSelector` before call dispatch. Did you verified that? Put `response_time` in html: you should see `all`. Then click a button that dispatch the change. You should now see `12`. Could you make this test?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I have made that test many times, it does show all, at first render but then it does not re render that's why I've made this post.

Comment: Have you also tried to log the state in reducer? You see response_time to 12?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito yes

Comment: This is a duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58850699/useselector-not-updating-when-store-has-changed-in-reducer-reactjs-redux

Answer (score -3):

It can be the nested `useEffect` dependency, could you try below?

```js
const { response_time } = useSelector(state => state.ad.filters);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('look', response_time)
  }, [response_time])
```

Answer (score -4):

it is probably updated, but the console.log() you are using is not inside a useEffect function, so it doesn't take the state change into consideration, try this:

```
const filters = useSelector(state => state.ad.filters);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('look', filters.response_time)
}, [filters.response_time])
```

instead of this:

```
const filters = useSelector(state => state.ad.filters);
console.log('look', filters.response_time)
```

Comment: I have tried, but it still does not console log the new value after the dispatch